# Travelling to Denmark with permit of stay receipt only

Tags: italy, denmark, turkish-citizens, italian-residents

I am a Turkish citizen, currently residing in Italy as a student. 
At the first time I was going to come to Italy, 2 years ago, I had acquired a 1-year valid D-type student Schengen visa from Italian embassy in Turkey and later, acquired a permit of stay after I arrived in Italy. 
Now my problem is, my permit of stay has expired lately, I am waiting for a new one, however it takes around 4-5 months. In other words, I will get my new permit around September-October. However, I have to travel to Denmark during summertime (preferable directly from Turkey, but from Italy if needed). Do you know if I can travel to other Schengen countries from Italy or from Turkey while I have only the receipt that states I have applied for the renewal of the permit, which was provided by post office.
If no, do you know if I can apply for a new D-type student Schengen visa when I go back to Turkey which will enable me to go to Denmark.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

No, you absolutely cannot, since you do not have a valid Schengen visa.

Italy allows you to stay on its territory while your visa extension is being processed. Even if you will leave Italy, you will almost certainly won't be able to get back until your visa extension is approved.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by *waiting* you mean you are holding the post receipt? In this case you can only go to Turkey and return to Italy; you definitely can't go to other Schengen countries especially from Turkey.

However, in these cases they might issue a temporary residence permit; you need to go to the police station (questura) and prove that you have an emergency to go to Denmark and submit a request for such permit.